# A false "Webpage not available" error

Tags: java, android, webview, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have been seeing this for quite some time.I am on ICS 4.0.4 tablet.
Most of the times when i open a `Webview` the page displays correctly.But sometimes,the same page doesnt display and i get a silly `Webpage not available`.

Note:

- The url has an extra `#`
- the pages i load are local
- this generally happens when i click a `href` which has an `onclick` firing the opening of a window with a webview.And i am simply setting `url` value at webview creation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: He is loading file from `assests` no internet connection needed.

Comment: Can you post your code? It will help us to find the root cause.

Comment: the root cause is the trailing #